# Data scrubbing and repairing a RAID1 mirror?

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid1, data-recovery, md

In Linux, if I have a software RAID1 mirror `/dev/md1` with N ≥ 1 active devices, what are the semantics of the `repair` command?

```sh
echo "repair" >/sys/block/md1/md/sync_action
```

Am I correct to assume that

- in case of 1 active device, the `repair` command does nothing,
- in case of 2 active devices, the `repair` command searches for data discrepancies and overwrites mismatched data of one of the devices with the mismatched data from the second device, and
- in case of 3 (or more) active devices, the `repair` command searches for data discrepancies, figures out (if possible) or decides which data contents are most prevalent and with this data overwrites the mismatched data on other devices?

I've read [Documentation/admin-guide/md.rst](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/admin-guide/md.rst) and even [Documentation/device-mapper/dm-raid.txt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/device-mapper/dm-raid.txt) from the Linux kernel documentation, but these are currently  not very informative. I've also tried to understand [drivers/md/raid1.c](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/md/raid1.c) but its not very well commented and I lack knowledge of Linux kernel internals to understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If code has not changed, 3-way RAID1 is not going to give you smart/better recovery comparable to BTRFS/ZFS scrubs.

From the main mdraid developer's [blog](http://neil.brown.name/blog/20100211050355):

> It is my position that if there is an inconsistency that needs to be
>   corrected then it should be corrected in a simple predictable way and
>   that any extra complexity is unjustified. For RAID1, that means
>   copying to first block over all the others

Give also a look [here](https://marc.info/?l=linux-raid&m=128386954813227&w=2). An abstract:

> It has already read all blocks and now compares them to see if they
>   are the same.  If not it copies the first to any that are different.